# Vehicle database design - Type, Make, Model, Vehicle

Tags: postgresql, database-design, django

I kindly ask you for advice, if I am correct with my DB design. I am writing an app in Django (it has its own ORM), which will use PostgreSQL.
My expectation is, that I will specify:

- Type (example: Automobile, Motorcycle, Boat, ...)
- Make (example: Honda, BMW, Audi, ...)
- Model (example: CBR1000, A6, A8, 535i, ...)
- Vehicle - all other info, like VIN, price, ...

So I think that the best way is to have Makes unique. I don't know, what to do with a **Type**. I think that the best way is to have a foreign key of a Type in a Model - because for example **Honda** can produce **Automobiles** and also **Motorcycles**. So by **Model** we can found, what vehicle type is it.

I want to make a web form filter (some kind of three linked dropdowns), where the user will select a **Type**, then it will filter out all **Makes** for that selected type. Then in another dropdown, he will select a Make and in the third dropdown, there will be shown all Models, which is available in that selection.
Something like a Copart has - Vehicle Finder on the right side of web page https://www.copart.com/vehicleFinder/

I hope that it makes sense, I have created a schema like this, and I am not just sure if it is usable and it is right. Here it is:

[image: vehicle database schema]

link to editor: https://dbdesigner.page.link/gS62T3GYPth2TAAbA

Thank you very much for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does 'type' have to be a separate table, and not just be an enum on 'model'? Then, when a user is doing a search of any type (via a dropdown or other method) it's just a filter on model (`... where type = ANY( VALUES ('BOAT'), ('MOTORBIKE')) ...`).

Comment: Where would you store type.name? If you put it in model, and the type.name changes for one of the types, then you'd have to update every record in model for that type.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Vehicle Database Schema sample.
https://dbdesigner.page.link/58jjJkYSs2iFPWQq9

Comment: While your design may answer the question, it would be best to edit it to describe what you have changed or improved, and why.